# Click a button within an iframe - pyppeteer

Tags: javascript, python, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I am trying to click a button inside an iframe using pyppeteer - the python version of puppeteer
However, I have drawn a blank. A simple page.click('#selector') does not seem to draw results and await page.waitForSelector('#selector') does not pick it up either

Could anyone advise?
The buttons prior to the iframe work fine
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the context to iframe.

There's an example in other thread: [Trying to click a button within an iframe with puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431296/trying-to-click-a-button-within-an-iframe-with-puppeteer)

And there's a solution from pptr docs (probably they're similar to python): https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.0.0&show=api-class-frame